Click on the first radio button selenium vba
I am stuck with the following html. I have this
<div class="quiz-slide-visualizer__content" style="pointer-events: all; width: 888px; height: 188px;"><div class="column-container" style="width: 50%;"><div class="choice-view choice-view_multiple-choice choice-view_columned"><div class="choice-view__choice-container" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__review-icons-container"><div class="choice-view__correct-icon"><svg width="14" height="10" viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M1.5 5.5L4.5625 8.75L12.25 1.25" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div><div class="choice-view__incorrect-icon"><svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M2 10L10 2M2 2L10 10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div></div><div class="choice-view__active-element-container"><input class="choice-view__mock-active-element" type="radio" name="choices" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__active-element choice-view__active-element_radio-button" aria-selected="false"><div class="outline-border"></div><div class="bg"></div><div class="inline-border"></div></div></div><div class="choice-attachment-container"><div class="choice-picture-attachment-view choice-picture-attachment-view_with-zoom choice-view__attachment-view" style="display: none;"></div></div><div class="choice-content"><div class="choice-view__rich-text-view published-rich-text"><p style="text-align:left;line-height:2em;padding-top:0em;padding-bottom:0em;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"><span style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">was built</span></p></div></div></div></div><div class="choice-view choice-view_multiple-choice choice-view_columned"><div class="choice-view__choice-container" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__review-icons-container"><div class="choice-view__correct-icon"><svg width="14" height="10" viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M1.5 5.5L4.5625 8.75L12.25 1.25" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div><div class="choice-view__incorrect-icon"><svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M2 10L10 2M2 2L10 10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div></div><div class="choice-view__active-element-container"><input class="choice-view__mock-active-element" type="radio" name="choices" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__active-element choice-view__active-element_radio-button" aria-selected="false"><div class="outline-border"></div><div class="bg"></div><div class="inline-border"></div></div></div><div class="choice-attachment-container"><div class="choice-picture-attachment-view choice-picture-attachment-view_with-zoom choice-view__attachment-view" style="display: none;"></div></div><div class="choice-content"><div class="choice-view__rich-text-view published-rich-text"><p style="text-align:left;line-height:2em;padding-top:0em;padding-bottom:0em;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"><span style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">was building</span></p></div></div></div></div></div><div class="column-container" style="width: 50%;"><div class="choice-view choice-view_multiple-choice choice-view_columned"><div class="choice-view__choice-container" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__review-icons-container"><div class="choice-view__correct-icon"><svg width="14" height="10" viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M1.5 5.5L4.5625 8.75L12.25 1.25" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div><div class="choice-view__incorrect-icon"><svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M2 10L10 2M2 2L10 10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div></div><div class="choice-view__active-element-container"><input class="choice-view__mock-active-element" type="radio" name="choices" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__active-element choice-view__active-element_radio-button" aria-selected="false"><div class="outline-border"></div><div class="bg"></div><div class="inline-border"></div></div></div><div class="choice-attachment-container"><div class="choice-picture-attachment-view choice-picture-attachment-view_with-zoom choice-view__attachment-view" style="display: none;"></div></div><div class="choice-content"><div class="choice-view__rich-text-view published-rich-text"><p style="text-align:left;line-height:2em;padding-top:0em;padding-bottom:0em;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal"><span style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;">were built</span></p></div></div></div></div><div class="choice-view choice-view_multiple-choice choice-view_columned"><div class="choice-view__choice-container" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__review-icons-container"><div class="choice-view__correct-icon"><svg width="14" height="10" viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M1.5 5.5L4.5625 8.75L12.25 1.25" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div><div class="choice-view__incorrect-icon"><svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <path d="M2 10L10 2M2 2L10 10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path></svg></div></div><div class="choice-view__active-element-container"><input class="choice-view__mock-active-element" type="radio" name="choices" aria-checked="false"><div class="choice-view__active-element choice-view__active-element_radio-button" aria-selected="false"><div class="outline-border"></div><div class="bg"></div><div class="inline-border"></div></div></div><div class="choice-attachment-container"><div class="choice-picture-attachment-view choice-picture-attachment-view_with-zoom choice-view__attachment-view" style="display: none;"></div></div><div class="choice-content"><div class="choice-view__rich-text-view published-rich-text"><p style="text-align:left;line-height:2em;padding-top:0em;padding-bottom:0em;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';color:#000000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal">​<span style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-size:24px;font-family: 'fnt0_65068', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;"> are built</span></p></div></div></div></div></div></div>

And I need to click on one of radio buttons .. I am using VBA selenium
I tried this .FindElementsByXPath("//input[@class='choice-view__mock-active-element']/following-sibling::div")(1).Click but got an error SeleniumError
I tried these lines and worked partially
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true');", .FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='choice-view__choice-container']")(1)
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');", .FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='choice-view__active-element choice-view__active-element_radio-button']")(1)

But it seems the option selected apparently but not really clicked

the "name" attribute is usually a good way to go with inputs.  Something like //input[@name='choices']  (just use the .click() method on the element once you find it...)
